# Mono undefined reference to `locale_charset'

Tags: linux, centos, mono

I am trying to compile mono from source and am getting this error.

../src/.libs/libeglib.a(libeglib_la-gunicode.o): In function `monoeg_g_get_charset':
/opt/mono-2.10.1/eglib/src/gunicode.c:312: undefined reference to`locale_charset'

I am compiling it on centos5. I have compiled it before on other machines (Centos too) so I have no idea whats wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. run ./configure
2. go to eglib/
3. open config.h and replace following string

   #define HAVE_LOCALCHARSET_H 1

by

```
 #define HAVE_LOCALCHARSET_H 0
```

Comment: This was needed also on Slackware 13.37 32bit.
Thank you for the reply.